# How to use regex to check a line contain exact 3 commas

Tags: c#, regex

I want to check if a line contain exact 3 commas, if I use:

```
^.+,.+,.+,.+$
```

then `1,2,3,4` will match , but also `1,2,3,4,5,6,7`
. How can I match `1,2,3,4` only?

Comment: Use a negative character class (or `\w` or something) instead of `.`.

Comment: Do you specifically want to solve this with regexes?

Answer (score 2):

The `.+$`  is giving you grief. Try `^[^,]+,[^,]+,[^,]+,[^,]+$`
The `.+$`  was actually matching all the remaining characters in your input string.

If you want to allow missing or null values use using `[^,]*`

If you want only numbers or null values try using `[0-9]*`

Comment: This is a correct answer, but you accidentally omitted a couple + in your first line, it should be  ^[^,]+,[^,]+,[^,]+,[^,]+$